# Python problem with connecting socket to server

Tags: python, sockets

I have written a simple program to connect a client to a server in python.
When I run this on my local network with my local IP address, everything works fine.
I've gotten a google cloud server and a linux VM on it. I've uploaded server.py onto the server,
but when I run it, I cannot connect from my computer with the client code.
I've tried pinging the server from my computer and that works. I also looked at which ports were being
listened to on the server side. When I left the code as below, port 5555 was not listed.
When I replaced the server in server.py by server = "", then tested for which ports were being listened to,
port 5555 was being used, but not by the public IP address, instead by the local one.

Here is the code (I've removed everything irrelevant to establishing the network connection):

server.py:

```
import socket
from _thread import *
import pickle

server = "34.89.182.513"
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((server, port))
except socket.error as e:
    str(e)

s.listen(4)
print("Waiting for a connection, Server Started")


def threaded_client(conn, player_id):
    pass  # I've removed this code, since it is not relevant to question


while True:
     conn, addr = s.accept()
     print("Connected to:", addr)
     start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn, 0))
```

client.py:

```
import socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect("34.89.182.513", 5555)
```

The google cloud VM lists two different IP addresses, one private and one public. I've been using the public
one. Does that have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: Is your firewall blocking incoming traffic at this port?

Comment: I do not know. I am using a google VM. As far as I know there is no firewall. How could I be sure that there is no firewall?

Comment: try to change the bind line "34.89.182.513", 5555 on the server side by ' ', 5555 on some site it's what they put to the bind line

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately it did not work. I looked into the Google documentation and created a firewall rule to open all ports to all source IP-Addresses. I applied this to the VM. It still did not work.